# Angular2 append params to template url

Tags: angular

In angular1, I had the habit to create a `httpProvider.interceptors` which appended a random variable (or a version number) to prevent the browser side cache of specific files. I used it most of the time for the template files.

How can I do the same thing in angular2 ?

Note : I cannot use any solution with the `HTTP` service as it does not seem to be used for loading the views templates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. The template system for building the view of a component uses directly the service XHR which is implemented in XHRImpl. You can view this in the `normalizeTemplate` method of the `TemplateNormalizer` class.

My solution was to extend this implementation and override the get method.

```
import { XHRImpl } from 'angular2/src/platform/browser/xhr_impl'
import { XHR } from 'angular2/compiler'

class VersionedXHRImpl extends XHRImpl {
  get(url) {
    const separator = url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&'
    url = url + separator + 'v=' + config.version
    return super.get(url)
  }
}

bootstrap(App, [
  provide(XHR, {useClass: VersionedXHRImpl})
])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you can do it easily as follows

```js
@Component({
    templateUrl : 'myTemplate.html?'+(new Date().getTime())
})
```

Comment: Yes. I thought of that. But I would like to do it for all templates in one go instead of setting it in each component.